# hangman game- update word list.python

Tags: python

Im writing a code for the game hangman. I need to write a function that gets: a word, a current pattern, and a letter, and returns the updated pattern (if the letter was in the word).

```
for example: update_word_pattern("apple", "_ _ _ l _", p)
will return: ("_ppl_")
```

I tried to write the code but i get the error message:

```
"    updated_pattern = pattern[:i] + letter[i] + pattern[i+1:]
IndexError: string index out of range"
```

Here is my code:

```
def update_word_pattern(word, pattern, letter):
    for i in range(len(pattern) - 1):
        if letter in word:
            updated_pattern = pattern[:i] + letter[i] + pattern[i+1:]
        print(updated_pattern)
    else:
        print(updated_pattern)

update_word_pattern("apple", "_ _ _ _ _", "p")
```

I dont really know how to solve this.I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you testing `if letter in word:` inside the `for` loop? Neither `letter` nor  `word` change inside the loop, so that test will give the same result every time. Also, you need to take account of the spaces in `pattern`. It would be simpler to make `pattern` a list the same length as `word`, and add the spaces when you print it, eg `pattern = ['_'] * len(word)`, and then you can print it by doing `print(' '.join(pattern))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to solve the homework for you, but your error stems from the fact that you are using:

```
letter[i]
```

But `len(letter) == 1` , so that throws the error you see  (you might want to do `letter` instead of `letter[i]`...).

Comment: Thanks. it did get rid of the error message but the output i got was wrong:_ _ _ _ p

Answer (score 0):

As Idos mentions, you are getting that `IndexError` because `letter[i]` is invalid when `i` > 0, since `letter` is a one char string.

The logic of your function doesn't make a lot of sense. Neither `letter` nor `word` change inside the function, so if you want to perform that `if letter in word` test it's a bit silly to do it inside a `for` loop. However, what you *really* need to test in the loop is if `letter` is equal to the current character of `word`.

Here's a repaired version of your code.

```
def update_pattern(word, pattern, letter):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == letter:
            pattern = pattern[:i] + letter + pattern[i+1:]
    return pattern

# test
word = "apple"
pattern = '_' * len(word)
for letter in 'petal':
    print(letter)
    pattern = update_pattern(word, pattern, letter)
    print(' '.join(pattern), end='\n\n')
```

**output**

```
p
_ p p _ _

e
_ p p _ e

t
_ p p _ e

a
a p p _ e

l
a p p l e
```

---

Here's a more efficient way that stores `pattern` in a list:

```
def update_pattern(word, pattern, letter):
    return [letter if w == letter else p
        for w, p in zip(word, pattern)]

# test
word = "apple"
pattern = ['_'] * len(word)
for letter in 'petal':
    print(letter)
    pattern = update_pattern(word, pattern, letter)
    print(' '.join(pattern), end='\n\n')
```

It gives identical output to my previous version.