# Program/loop only working partially

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am working on a hangman script but it isn't working properly.
In this example I use the word "curiosities" as the word to guess, since it has three "i"s.
F(or some reason styling is weird so in block):

```
The desired output is "_ _ _ i _ _ i _ i _ _"
But I can only get to  "_ _ _ i _ _ i _ _ _ _"
```

here's the main part of the code:

```
def alter(output_word, guessed_letter, the_word):
    checkword = the_word
    #print ("outputword:",output_word)
    previous = 0
    fully_checked = False
    current_count = 0
    while fully_checked == False:
        global add_number
        checkword = checkword[previous:]
        add_number = previous + add_number

        #print ("..",checkword)
        if guessed_letter in checkword:

            current_count = current_count + 1
            print (">>>",current_count)
            the_index = (checkword.index(guessed_letter))+add_number
          #  print (output_word)
           #  print (the_index)
           # print (guessed_letter)
            output_word= output_word[:the_index-1] + guessed_letter + output_word[the_index:]

            previous = the_index+1  
        else:
            fully_checked = True
            checkword = the_word
            add_number = 0
    print (' '.join(output_word))
    checklist(current_count)  

def checklist(current_count):
    print ("checklist")
    print (current_count)
    global total_count
    total_count = total_count + current_count
    print ("total count is", total_count)
```

Somewhere else in the code to trigger this all(the_word being curiosities and guessed_letter being i):

```
if guessed_letter in the_word:
    alter(output_word, guessed_letter, the_word)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Derorrist points out, there are a couple of flaws in your code's logic, the main one being you've mixed up the index of `output_word` with that of `checkword`.

I've fixed those bugs and condensed your code a little. `add_number` doesn't need to be a global, and in general you should avoid using modifiable globals unless you really need them, because they destroy code modularity.

```
total_count = 0

def alter(output_word, guessed_letter, checkword):
    previous = add_number = current_count = 0
    while True:
        checkword = checkword[previous:]
        if guessed_letter in checkword:
            the_index = checkword.index(guessed_letter)
            offset = the_index + add_number
            print(">>>", current_count, the_index, offset)
            output_word= output_word[:offset] + guessed_letter + output_word[offset + 1:]
            previous = the_index + 1
            add_number += previous
            current_count += 1
        else:
            break

    print(' '.join(output_word))
    checklist(current_count) 
    return output_word

def checklist(current_count):
    global total_count

    print("checklist")
    print(current_count)
    total_count += current_count
    print("total count is", total_count, end='\n\n')

# test

the_word = "curiosities"
output_word = "_" * len(the_word)
print(' '.join(output_word))

for guessed_letter in 'cisotrue':
    output_word = alter(output_word, guessed_letter, the_word)
```

**output**

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
>>> 0 0 0
c _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
checklist
1
total count is 1

>>> 0 3 3
>>> 1 2 6
>>> 2 1 8
c _ _ i _ _ i _ i _ _
checklist
3
total count is 4

>>> 0 5 5
>>> 1 4 10
c _ _ i _ s i _ i _ s
checklist
2
total count is 6

>>> 0 4 4
c _ _ i o s i _ i _ s
checklist
1
total count is 7

>>> 0 7 7
c _ _ i o s i t i _ s
checklist
1
total count is 8

>>> 0 2 2
c _ r i o s i t i _ s
checklist
1
total count is 9

>>> 0 1 1
c u r i o s i t i _ s
checklist
1
total count is 10

>>> 0 9 9
c u r i o s i t i e s
checklist
1
total count is 11
```

---

FWIW, there are simpler ways to do this that are also more efficient. Eg, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40946952/4014959) are a couple I wrote the other day.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed the index of `output_word` with the index of the sliced `checkword`.

Replace `previous = the_index+1`

with

`previous = checkword.index(guessed_letter)+1`

Also there's a small slicing mishap in `output_word= output_word[:the_index-1] + guessed_letter + output_word[the_index:]`

It should be

`output_word= output_word[:the_index] + guessed_letter + output_word[the_index+1:]`

Output:

`_ _ _ i _ _ i _ i _ _`

Comment: @PM2Ring was just about to add it to the answer, thanks for that

Comment: No problem. I was just about to post an answer myself, but you beat me to it. :)